How to set a cutoff value for axis
Is it possible to set maximum value for an axis but which adjusts itself so it's never higher than the measured values? I think neither max nor softmax setting allows for this flexibility but can't find the correct setting.
Example:
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  "chart": {
    "type": "scatter"
  },
  "series": [{
    "type": "scatter",
    "name": "Measures",
    "data": [{"name": "OK","x": 113180, "y": 11}, {"name": "OK","x": 108411,"y": 5}, {"name": "OK","x": 113607,"y": 4}, {"name": "OK","x": 124644,"y": 4}, {"name": "Edge","x": 117135,"y": 45, "color":"black"}, {"name": "Outbound","x": 109998,"y": 100, "color":"red"}]
  }],
  "xAxis": {
    "categories": "",
    "title": {
      "text": "Cap"
    },
    "reversed": false
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "min": 0
  }
});


I want to avoid displaying "outlers" like the "Outbound" measure (the red dot), so i want to have a cutoff of 50.
If i set yAxis.max = 50 it looks good:

But if we remove both the red and black dot, the maximum measure becomes 11, and it starts to look ugly with max = 50:

Here, there's a lot of space, in this case i want highchart to be able to figure out that maximum value is = 11 and adapt the graph.
Is there a setting for this kind of intelligent cutoff? I have very little means of doing something dynamic nor filter the values ahead of time

In the load function, you can update the yAxis max option to the highest point's value from a series.
API references:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0s7phkfx/
chart: {
 events: {
  load: function() {
    const chart = this,
      yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
      series = chart.series[0];

    yAxis.update({
      max: series.dataMax
    });
  }
}

},

Thank you for your answer, unfortunately, i cannot embed any javascript inside the code, because the system that displays these charts only accepts the static json object. Is there a way around it?

You can also calculate and set the yAxis.max option by yourself in the config but for that you need to know your data beforehand.
